# Debug, System functions (fopen,fclose,fread,fwrite,...) and for loop in Google Test C

Tags: c, unit-testing, googletest

I am using Google Test to test C code but I encounter with the problem **Write Stub for system functions** like: fopen,fclose,fread,fwrite,memcpy,memset,stat,...I don't known how to **Stub** its input/output correctly to convenient for testing without having to care about real data. Example below:

```
bool open_file(void)
{
   FILE *srcfd;
   FILE *destfd;
   int dataLen;
   bool retVal=false;
   char buffer[255];
   srcfd = fopen("srcFileName", "r");
    if(NULL != srcfd)
    {
        destfd = fopen("destFileName", "w+");
        if(NULL != destfd)
        {
            retVal = true;

            while ((true == retVal) &&
                    ((dataLen = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), srcfd)) > 0))
            {
                if (fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), dataLen, destfd) != dataLen)
                {
                    retVal = false;
                }
            }

            fclose(destfd);

        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s: Failed to create file '%s'...\n",
                    __func__, "destFileName");
        }
        fclose(srcfd);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s: Failed to create file '%s'...\n", __func__, "srcFileName");
    }
return retVal;
}
```

Comment: In your question, point 2 is not clear and point 4 is impossible to answer, asking "how do I debug" is too broad.

Comment: I mean, I need some example and the way to fix it

Comment: give example of the code you want to test and function you want to stub.

Comment: I have give a example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always write your own definition of the external function (stub) to support your test without caring about the real implementation of the function.

To make your life easier, you can use some already-existed stub framework such as [Fake Function Framework](https://github.com/meekrosoft/fff).

Example in your case, to test `bool open_file(void)` with the stub of `fopen` you can do like this in your test file:

```
#include "fff.h"
DEFINE_FFF_GLOBALS;
//fake fopen, be sure about the prototype of the faked function
FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(FILE*, fopen, const char*, const char*);
```

And in the test case:

```
TEST_F(Test_open_file, stub_fopen){
   //call the function under test
   open_file();
   //check number of time fopen called
   ASSERT_EQ(fopen_fake.call_count, 1);
   //check input parameter
   ASSERT_EQ(strncmp(fopen_fake.arg0_val, "destFileName", 100), 0);
}
```

But be clear that stub is not always a good solution, do stub only when you really don't care about the real implementation of the external function and you just want the output of that function for your test purpose. Sometimes, call the real external function is better.

*(I strike the bellowed texts because you modified your question)*

<s>You cannot control a local variable in the function under tested from your test case, you need to control it through global variables, function inputs or stub return value... whatever interfaces that set the value for that local variable you can interact with in your test cases.</s>

Comment: Thanks. I have given a example function that need to tested

Comment: Ok.I got it, the best answer